# Impulse acceleration directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum

> A post is driven into the ground by means of a blow from a
>   pile-driver. The pile-driver falls from rest from a height of 1.6 m
>   above the top of the post.
>
> (a) Show that the speed of the pile-driver just before it hits the
>   post is 5.6 m s–1.
>
> The post has mass 6 kg and the pile-driver has mass 78 kg. When the
>   pile-driver hits the top of the post, it is assumed that the there is
>   no rebound and that both then move together with the same speed.
>
> (b) Find the speed of the pile-driver and the post immediately after
>   the pile-driver has hit the post.
>
> The post is brought to rest by the action of a resistive force from
>   the ground acting for 0.06 s. By modelling this force as constant
>   throughout this time,
>
> (c) find the magnitude of the resistive force,
>
> ...

I'm stuck on part (C), the answer is $(78+6)(g+a) = 84(9.8+86.6)$

but the accelerations caused by gravity and the force of the drop are in opposing directions; so, why are they added, instead of subtracted?

Comment: It's just vector addition but you have to take into account of direction ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

The deceleration is downwards so the acceleration $a$ is upwards. If the resistive force is $F$ upwards then applying Newton's 2nd Law the net force on the pile is
$F-mg=ma$
$F=m(g+a)$.